# Spring Cloud Config Client is not reporting health

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have implemented Cloud Config Server, and (finally) is working fine, and providing the configuration to the clients. I'm using version 3.0.1 of Config Server (I had to upgrade because some bugs in 3.0.0).

But my final step, to provide the health is not working.

In the actuator/health of every project, it report always:

```
    "clientConfigServer": {
        "status": "UNKNOWN",
        "details": {
            "error": "no property sources located"
        }
    },
```

I have added the enabled: true in both, bootstrap.yml and application.yml

```
# Development only: Adjust or remove in production management:
  endpoint.health.show-details: "ALWAYS"
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
  health:
    circuitbreakers.enabled: true
    ratelimiters.enabled: true
    config.enabled: true

health.config.enabled: true
```

NOTE: The config server is in 3.0.1, but the client is in 3.0.0. I cannot upgrade the client because dependencies.
Any suggestion or clue will be welcome!

Comment: There are bugs in the client too, why can't you update it?

Comment: I missed your comment. In this moment I have a lot of dependencies on Cloud BOM 2020.0.0. I will try to update to 2020.0.1, and recheck! Thanks for comment!

Comment: @Sourcerer - did it work after you have updated both config server and client to the same version ?